# How can I get DateTime.DaysInMonth without weekends?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do I get in C# the number of days in a month without Friday and Saturday?

Comment: Well you'd just iterate for each day and remove 1 for each friday and saturday from a counter initialized to regular DaysInMonth I guess.

Comment: @Camilo Martin - what do you mean 'iterate for each day'? DateTime.DaysInMonth retrieve an int and not a collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Date Compare: Count the amount of working days since a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165887/net-date-compare-count-the-amount-of-working-days-since-a-date)

Comment: @Erez: think outside the box, if DateTime.DaysInMonth gives for you an incorrect number, then you should do some other things. Like making 2 dates (1/1/2010 and 1/2/2010) and iterate from date1 to date2 skipping the weekends.

Comment: You can do it without loops or iteration, look at my answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, quick and dirty:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int month = DateTime.Today.Month;
        int year = DateTime.Today.Year;

        int daysInMonthMinusFridayAndSaturday = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month); i++)
        {
            DateTime thisDay = new DateTime(year,month,i);
            if(thisDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday && thisDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                daysInMonthMinusFridayAndSaturday += 1;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(daysInMonthMinusFridayAndSaturday);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Obligatory LINQ solution:

```
int days = Enumerable.Range( 1, DateTime.DaysInMonth( year, month ) )
                     .Select( day => new DateTime( year, month, day ) )
                     .Count( d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                                  d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid loops or iterations and do it like this:

```
int GetWorkDays(int year, int month)
{
    var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1).DayOfWeek;
    var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

    // count whole weeks first            
    var wholeWeeks = daysInMonth / 7;
    var extraDays = daysInMonth % 7;

    // calculate the overlap of the "remainder days" with the weekend.
    var lastDayOfMonth = (int) (firstDayOfMonth + extraDays - 1);
    var overlapStart = Math.Max((int) firstDayOfMonth, (int) DayOfWeek.Friday);
    var overlapEnd = Math.Min(lastDayOfMonth, (int) DayOfWeek.Saturday);
    var weekendOverlap = Math.Max(0, overlapEnd - overlapStart + 1);

    // substract weekend days
    return daysInMonth - wholeWeeks * 2 - weekendOverlap;
}
```

Comment: Why to care about a little bit of performance on something so simple? It's not like it's going to take more than a few miliseconds at worst.

Comment: @Camilo Martin: Because it's nicer :) I agree there's no real-life significance. At least until someone invents really long months.