# Get number of days in any month without saturday and sunday?

Tags: c#

There is an input string field "Januray 2020". I want to calculate total number of working days in the given month and year.

Can we do this in simple c#?

Comment: Do public holidays or other special dates count as "working days", too?

Comment: Hi and welcome, add some sample input, the corresponding sample output and show us some code that you have already tried!

Comment: Does it answer your question? [How can I get DateTime.DaysInMonth without weekends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482297/how-can-i-get-datetime-daysinmonth-without-weekends)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get DateTime.DaysInMonth without weekends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482297/how-can-i-get-datetime-daysinmonth-without-weekends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've not defined what a work day is you can use this function to iterate over all the days in a month according to a predicate:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> WorkDaysInMonth(int year, int month, Func<DateTime,bool> isNonWorkDay)
{
    var now = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

    while(now.Month == month)
    {
        if(!isNonWorkDay(now))
        {
            yield return now;
        }

        now = now.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

So, if you just want to create weekends as non work days then you'd get the total like this:

```
var weekdays = WorkDaysInMonth(2020, 1, d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
var total = weekdays.Count();
```

Likewise if you've got some calendar system that tells you about public holidays then you can add a call into the predicate to see if the supplied date is a holiday.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "January 2020";
var d = DateTime.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine(d);
var x = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month);
Console.WriteLine(x);
var w = Enumerable.Range(1, x)
                 .Select( i => new DateTime( d.Year, d.Month, i))
                 .Count( i => i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday );
Console.WriteLine(w);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sp3qYo